# Blog post stuck in drafts

Tags: blog

Please help me publish my first blog post. It keeps saying it's "published" but when I check the page it says nothing found, then I see my post still in drafts.

Comment: Have you tried checking with another theme or removing the plugins?

Answer (score 0):

> when I check the page it says nothing found, then I see my post still in drafts

It is not clear what is **nothing found**? 
Does this mean you have the 404 error?

You may have the problem with either the theme or some plugin or with the caching.
You may alter the theme and try disabling all te plugins or opening the page from the incognito mode of the web browser, and let us know.

> It keeps saying it's "published"

I guess you checked that from the WordPress dashboard. Can you confirm? Can you check from this page: `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` and try setting the Plain permalink.

[image]

Let us know if this works.